# Windows 8 Xaml object binding

Tags: c#, json, binding

ive got a Problem in Binding a Stringmember of an Object of an List into the .xaml
On the xaml.cs i do this:

grdEvents.ItemsSource = await m.GetEvents(); //wait for the returned list after an JSONcall

the class looks like this:

```
public class getevents
{
    public class Result{ //returned list
         public string xy {get; set;} //access granted
         public Image x {get; set;}
     }

    public class Image{
         public string x ; //dont know how to acces?
    }

}
```

How is it possible to get access to the Member of the Imageobject?

Thx, Roman

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `Image.x` a *property*, not a *field*.  If you do that, you should be ablet o bind to it directly via `"{Binding Path=Image.x}"` (provided you have an Image property in your events class of the Image class).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I cant change the Image to a property , because it is a fix JSON return, defined by the API of the Server. Any other Solutions?

Comment: @RomanMauricéHlfn You'll need to wrap it in a class that has it as a property - bindings only work against properties, not fields.